# XSL : trying to use the same counter for different templates

Tags: xml, xslt

I am working on different tests which have several steps. The matter is that the steps and the tests are at the same tag (and it is impossible to change it). Having an example would be easier (it is not the original code) :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<?xml-stylesheet href="new 1.xsl" type="text/xsl"?>

<root>
    <file id="0">
        <artist>Metallica</artist>
        <album>Kill'Em All</album>
        <Message>First Album</Message>
    </file>
    <file id="1">
        <artist>Iron Maiden</artist>
        <album>Piece of Mind</album>
        <Message>The one with The Trooper song</Message>
    </file>
    <file id="2">
        <artist>U2</artist>
        <album>War</album>
        <Message>There is a child on the cover</Message>
    </file>
    <file id="3">
        <artist/>
        <album/>
        <Message>End of the year 1983</Message>
    </file>
    <file id="4">
        <artist>Van Halen</artist>
        <album>1984</album>
        <Message>Hot for teacher</Message>
    </file>
    <file id="5">
        <artist>Iron Maiden</artist>
        <album>Powerslave</album>
        <Message>Best</Message>
    </file>
    <file id="6">
        <artist>Mercyful Fate</artist>
        <album>Dont Break the Oath</album>
        <Message>with King Diamond</Message>
    </file>
    <file id="7">
        <artist/>
        <album/>
        <Message>End of the year 1984</Message>
    </file>
    <file id="8">
        <artist>Dire Straits</artist>
        <album>Brother in Arms</album>
        <Message>Money for Nothing</Message>
    </file>
    <file id="9">
        <artist>Megadeth</artist>
        <album>Killing is my Business</album>
        <Message>Megadave</Message>
    </file>
    <file id="10">
        <artist/>
        <album/>
        <Message>End of the year 1985</Message>
    </file>
    <file id="11">
        <artist>Metallica</artist>
        <album>Master of Puppets</album>
        <Message>perfect</Message>
    </file>
    <file id="12">
        <artist>Slayer</artist>
        <album>Reign in Blood</album>
        <Message>so good</Message>
    </file>
    <file id="13">
        <artist>Megadeth</artist>
        <album>Peace Sells</album>
        <Message>but who's buying</Message>
    </file>
    <file id="14">
        <artist>Judas Priest</artist>
        <album>Turbo</album>
        <Message>Seen better</Message>
    </file>
    <file id="15">
        <artist/>
        <album/>
        <Message>End of the year 1986</Message>
    </file>
    <file id="16">
        <artist>GNR</artist>
        <album>Appetite for Destruction</album>
        <Message>best album ever</Message>
    </file>
    <file id="17">
        <artist/>
        <album/>
        <Message>End of the year 1987</Message>
    </file>
    <file id="18">
        <artist/>
        <album/>
        <Message>End of the year 1988</Message>
    </file>
    <file id="19">
        <artist>Motley Crue</artist>
        <album>Dr.Feelgood</album>
        <Message>hair metal as it's root</Message>
    </file>
    <file id="20">
        <artist>Overkill</artist>
        <album>Years of Decay</album>
        <Message>OK</Message>
    </file>
    <file id="21">
        <artist/>
        <album/>
        <Message>End of the year 1989</Message>
    </file>
</root>
```

As you can see, the test "end of the year 198X' is at the same tag than the steps 'artist' or 'album'.
The goal is to display if Metallica released an album in year 198X or not.
 Here is my XSLT code :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:template name="principal">
    <xsl:param name="counter">0</xsl:param>
    <xsl:choose>
        <xsl:when test="contains(root/artist[@id='$counter'], 'Metallica')">
            <xsl:template name="second-one">
                <xsl:if test="not(contains(root/Message[@id='$counter'], 'year'))">
                    <xsl:call-template name="second-one">
                        <xsl:with-param name="counter" select="$counter+1"/>
                    </xsl:call-template>
                </xsl:if>
                <xsl:value-of select="root/Message[@id='$counter+1']"> Metallica released an album </xsl:value-of>              
            </xsl:template>
        </xsl:when>
        <xsl:otherwise>
            <xsl:template name="second-two">
                <xsl:choose>
                    <xsl:when test="contains(root/Message[@id='$counter'], 'year')">
                        <xsl:value-of select="//document[@id='$counter']/Message"/>
                        <td> no Metallica </td>
                    </xsl:when>
                    <xsl:otherwise>
                        <xsl:call-template name="second-two">
                            <xsl:with-param name="counter" select="$counter+1"/>
                        </xsl:call-template>
                    </xsl:otherwise>
                </xsl:choose>
            </xsl:template>
        </xsl:otherwise>
    </xsl:choose>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

So I have two questions :

1. Can I use the counter `$counter` in the template 'principal' and still having the same value of $counter in templates 'second-one' and 'second-two'?
2. Editix says that I can't use  (line 5) and I don't know why.

Thank you for your answer

Comment: "*The goal is to display if Metallica released an album in year 198X or not.*" What exactly does that mean? Is "x" known (if yes, where is it coming from?), or do you just want to see if they had an album in that decade?

Comment: Simple way to say if Metallica released an album in year 1983, or 1984, 1985,1986,1987,1988,1989...

Comment: Is it correct to assume that the entries are in chronological order, and the ones without artist or album are "markers" that signify the end of each year? -- P.S. I still don't understand fully your goal: it seems your list only covers the years 1983-1989, so you would only need to see if Metallica appears  **anywhere** in it.

Comment: It is correct ! 

It is just an example that I made quickly. 
The problem here is that all the 'file' are children of the root, whether it is a description of the album or the message of the end of the year.
Then, when the program sees 'Metallica', how does it know it has to say that this album was released that year? By finding the moment when there is no artist/album.

Comment: IMHO, you should start by grouping the albums by year. Then everything will be much easier.

Comment: I wish I could, I can't modify the original XML

Comment: You don't need to modify the original XML. I meant group them within the XSLT. Or just assign a year to each (real) album. I'll post an answer showing how to do that.

Comment: P.S. Please indicate XSLT 1.0 or 2.0.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you start by assigning a year to each 'real" album, you will have something that's much easier to work with.

The following example does nothing but create a table of all the albums and their years, but you could just as well store the result in a variable and then work from there.

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:key name="k" match="file[string(artist) and string(album)]" use="following-sibling::file[not(string(artist) or string(album))][1]/@id" />

<xsl:template match="/root">
    <table border="1">
        <xsl:for-each select="file[not(string(artist) or string(album))]">
            <xsl:variable name="year" select="substring-after(Message, 'End of the year ')" />
            <xsl:for-each select="key('k', @id)">
                <tr>
                    <td><xsl:value-of select="artist"/></td>
                    <td><xsl:value-of select="album"/></td>
                    <td><xsl:value-of select="$year"/></td>
                </tr>
            </xsl:for-each>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </table>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**Result**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<table border="1">
   <tr>
      <td>Metallica</td>
      <td>Kill'Em All</td>
      <td>1983</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
      <td>Iron Maiden</td>
      <td>Piece of Mind</td>
      <td>1983</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
      <td>U2</td>
      <td>War</td>
      <td>1983</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
      <td>Van Halen</td>
      <td>1984</td>
      <td>1984</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
      <td>Iron Maiden</td>
      <td>Powerslave</td>
      <td>1984</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
      <td>Mercyful Fate</td>
      <td>Dont Break the Oath</td>
      <td>1984</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
      <td>Dire Straits</td>
      <td>Brother in Arms</td>
      <td>1985</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
      <td>Megadeth</td>
      <td>Killing is my Business</td>
      <td>1985</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
      <td>Metallica</td>
      <td>Master of Puppets</td>
      <td>1986</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
      <td>Slayer</td>
      <td>Reign in Blood</td>
      <td>1986</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
      <td>Megadeth</td>
      <td>Peace Sells</td>
      <td>1986</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
      <td>Judas Priest</td>
      <td>Turbo</td>
      <td>1986</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
      <td>GNR</td>
      <td>Appetite for Destruction</td>
      <td>1987</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
      <td>Motley Crue</td>
      <td>Dr.Feelgood</td>
      <td>1989</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
      <td>Overkill</td>
      <td>Years of Decay</td>
      <td>1989</td>
   </tr>
</table>
```

**rendered as:**

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much ! I now understand what you meant. 
I haven't thinked about xsl:key, which will be the solution of my program.

Comment: It's even easier in XSLT 2.0, using `group-ending-with`.

Comment: Good solution. The general principle here is, if you want to work with messy input XML, the best way is always to write a pipeline that starts by producing clean XML, and then uses this as input to the stylesheet that does the real work. A great advantage of this is that the messy->clean transformation is highly reusable, and will make all subsequent transforms using the same input XML much easier to write.

Answer (score 0):

1. Yes you can, [`xsl:with-param` is used to pass a parameter into a template](http://www.w3.org/TR/xslt20/#element-with-param)

However, the template must expect it, so the template needs a [`xsl:param` declaration](http://www.w3.org/TR/xslt20/#element-param)

2. The reason that line 5 is failing is likely due to the fact that [`xsl:when` can only take sequence-constructor children](http://www.w3.org/TR/xslt20/#element-when) [(literals or instructions)](http://www.w3.org/TR/xslt20/#dt-sequence-constructor), and  [`xsl:template` is a declaration](http://www.w3.org/TR/xslt20/#element-template), not an instruction.

So, move that template out to be a child of `xsl:stylesheet`, add a `param` declaration to it, and add an appropriate `call-template` instruction to your `when` instruction, and it should at least be syntactically correct.

However, using a counter to iterate over elements in a named template is not particularly idomatic XSLT.  Use a template with a `match` attribute instead, and let XSLT handle the business of applying the template to the appropriate nodes in order.

Comment: Thank you for your quick answer!
So I have moved the templates as children of the stylesheet, but the call-template will their still be recursives?